# Practice to ensure ViewModel state doesn't change after validation

Tags: validation, design-patterns, mvvm, architecture, viewmodel

If `Controller` first validates `ViewModel` properties and then uses `ViewModel` properties, there may be small chance that `ViewModel` state may change to invalid between validation and usage, resulting in exceptional control flow.

Is there any common practice or pattern to ensure `ViewModel` state doesn't change and / or properties can be safely used after validation?

Answer (score 2):

By keeping the state immutable, you can ensure that there is no change between validation and usage.

For instance:

```
class MyViewModel {
   property MyImmutableState state;
}

class MyController {
   private MyViewModel viewModel;
   private doSomething() {
      MyImmutableState state = viewModel.state;
      if (isValid(state))
         // because state is immutable, this is thread-safe
         doSomething(state);
   }
}
```

The key to making this work efficiently is that `MyImmutableState` should be not only immutable but also a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) (i.e. a data structure that keeps its old versions while being modified, typically via structural sharing). Libraries for such immutable collections exist in different languages.

1. Javascript: [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)
2. .Net: [System.Collections.Immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.aspx)
3. Java: http://www.javaslang.io/
4. Python: [pyrsistent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrsistent/)

Any function you apply to such a collection will return a new collection and leave the original one untouched. This way, the collection can be shared safely, without the need for locking.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that: 1) `ViewModel` and it's collections still remain mutable and suitable for bidirectional binding to `View`? 2) Immutable objects are used as much as possible for property values and inside collections? 3) Each `ViewModel` property value is captured into function scope variable to be later used in validation and business logic?

Comment: 1) You can do bidirectional binding, or you can use a one-directional architecture as in [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/). 2) Your entire state can be a single big map (which is like a JSON object). If you're using a persistent data structure for this, partial updates to this map are efficient, due to structural sharing. 3) You can capture the entire state into function scope, or any part of it, depending on what suits your design more. Both will be equally efficient.